# How to limit JPasswordField to 4 digits?

Tags: java, jpasswordfield

I just saw some questions here, but none of them resolve the problem for me. I have got a `JPasswordField` and I need that the user **cannot** input more than 4 digits in the EscPin `JPasswordField`

```
private void EscPinActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private javax.swing.JButton Entrar;
private javax.swing.JTextField EscNConta;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField EscPin;
private javax.swing.JLabel Logo;
private javax.swing.JLabel NConta;
private javax.swing.JLabel Pin;
private javax.swing.JButton Sair;
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me

Comment: @Carcigenicate just doesnt work, is there a way to do it without creat a new class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the internal **Document** of **JPasswordField**. try this it will work.

```
PlainDocument d=(PlainDocument) jPasswordField1.getDocument();
d.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter(){

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            String string =fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength())+text;

            if(string.length() <= 4)
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }



    });
```

Comment: And where i put this? i put in the `private void` of the JPasswordField and the user  can put more than 4 digits

Comment: Inside the constructor.

Comment: @Rui Maia can you please accept the answer. It would help me a lot.